# Adobe Air launch a web page under Safari instead stagewebview

Tags: actionscript-3, air

Is it possible to open a webpage by launching Safari under iOS instead of stagewebview?

(note i have tried the URLrequest, which not work on the iDevice).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Use the navigateToURL function. It should automatically open the link in the actual safari browser.

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.domain.com"));
```

Comment: I think i have tried that, and it failed? have you tested it out already?

Comment: updated answer to show what I've used and how it should be written.

Comment: Thanks i will give it another go again today, see if it works or not.